# How do I group a date field to get quarterly results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a job table that holds jobs and leaddate is the field for the job entry.

The result I want to get is the number of jobs I have in each quarter. My query counts jobs of each date in the leaddate field.

**Here is the query**

```
select count(jobid) as jobcount, leaddate
from jobs
where contactid='19249'
group by leaddate
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think this should do the job:

```
SELECT YEAR(leaddate) AS year, QUARTER(leaddate) AS quarter, COUNT(jobid) AS jobcount
  FROM jobs
 WHERE contactid = '19249'
 GROUP BY YEAR(leaddate), QUARTER(leaddate)
 ORDER BY YEAR(leaddate), QUARTER(leaddate)
```

Comment: Mysql always return ordered result set after `GROUP BY` and if i remember correctly - there os no optimizations, that will prevent of re-sorting already sorting set. Thus - this can be a little slower.

Comment: @zerkms: OK; I bow to your knowledge of MySQL.  With other DBMS, GROUP BY does not guarantee sorted order (for example, with parallel data query across on a range fragmented table where the range is based on leaddate), but the optimizer does avoid unnecessary work.  Just remember that GROUP BY is spelled differently from ORDER BY for a reason and other DBMS need both.

Comment: indeed, for oracle dbms it will not work. Details about mysql (Seems like I made small mistake, or may be not even small): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html" If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted...". PS: to search at mysql.com you need to log in oracle network. They must be kidding o_O

Answer (score 6):

Supposing you have a valid date or datetime field:

```
select count(jobid) as jobcount, YEAR(leaddate) yr, QUARTER(leaddate) qt
from jobs
where contactid='19249'
group by yr, qt
```

Comment: It works great as long as your start-of-quarter dates are 1st Jan, 1st Apr, 1st Jul, 1st Oct.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: since OP did not explain what quarter definition he expects to get - I've chosen the simpler way ;-)

Comment: Do you need YEAR(leaddate) and/or QUARTER(leaddate) in the select list instead of the raw leaddate?

Comment: Yep, changed the query to be more ansi-sql correct (it is not though, since aliases is not valid `GROUP BY` arguments there, but they make mysql query dialect so handy)

Answer (score 1):

I usually combine quarter and year into a single YEAR-QUARTER field:

```
select jobid, count(jobid) as jobcount, 
CONCAT( YEAR(leaddate),'-',QUARTER(leaddate) ) as year_qtr
from jobs
where contactid='19249'
group by year_qtr
```

RETURNS data like:

```
19249, 324, 2011-3
19249,   4, 2011-2
19249,  34, 2011-1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Quarter function to get a quarter from date:

```
select count(jobid) as jobcount, QUARTER(leaddate) as qt, YEAR(leaddate) as year
from jobs
where contactid='19249'
group by year,qt
```

Comment: Hello,

this works in  such a way that it grabs quaters no matter what year it way.  I wanted a query that outputs the count of quaters of each year seperately   .. like 4 quater of 2011 .. 4 quater of 2010 and so on

Comment: @Abhinab Kayastha: fixed in my answer ;-)