# MySQL - Selecting a weeks worth of data from week beginning date

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Trying to do a select but can't seem to master the art of this particular one. 
This is what I have tried:

```
select user_id,date,monday_am_task from users,week,timesheet_submission where user_id='1' and date='2015-04-06';
```

However it says it is too ambiguous. This is basically what I want to do. If the user_id=1 and the date is in between 2015-04-06 then show the data. By between and the date I mean this, I have setup a week table, this includes the week_number, week_id and date. Date is referred to as the week commencing date. So with my select statement I am trying to select the date that will pull all the data for that week, if that makes sense?

Week Table:

```
mysql> select * from week;
+---------+------+------------+
| week_id | week | date       |
+---------+------+------------+
|       1 | 1    | 2014-12-29 |
|       2 | 2    | 2015-01-05 |
|       3 | 3    | 2015-01-12 |
|       4 | 4    | 2015-01-19 |
|       5 | 5    | 2015-01-26 |
|       6 | 6    | 2015-02-02 |
|       7 | 7    | 2015-02-09 | etc...
```

Users:

```
mysql> select user_id, username, level from users;
+---------+----------+-------+
| user_id | username | level |
+---------+----------+-------+
|       1 | tom      |     1 |
|       2 | owain    |     2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user_id, date, timesheet_id, monday_am_task from timesheet_submission;
+---------+---------------------+--------------+----------------+
| user_id | date                | timesheet_id | monday_am_task |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+----------------+
|       1 | 2015-04-10 12:44:54 |           34 |              5 |
+---------+---------------------+--------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Use explicit join and give each table an alias name and finally use the column as `aliasname.columname` the problem will disappear.

Comment: Rewrite your query using explicit `join` syntax and qualify all the column names with table names.  You'll will find that the problem will go away.

Comment: Could a example be demonstrated please?

Comment: Can you make an edit to show the table structure of those three tables? At least with the columns you are querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when a column name exists in one or more of the selected tables. In this case, it appears to be `user_id` because it is in both users and timesheet_submission.

In addition, while it is all personal preference, many people prefer to use the `JOIN` syntax instead of listing multiple tables in the `FROM` clause. The second option creates a Cartesian product, which is what you are experiencing, and unless you set the proper conditions to relate a table, you can get very odd results like the ones you have now.

In short, the join syntax may look like this:

```
SELECT [columns]
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.relatedColumn = t1.relatedColumn;
```

For your tables, you can join users to timesheet_submission, and timesheet_submission to week, although that one is tricky because there is no direct link. To break my answer down a bit, I would start by getting all timesheet submissions for user_id 1 with a join like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, ts.date, ts.monday_am_task
FROM users u
JOIN timesheet_submission ts ON ts.user_id = u.user_id AND u.user_id = 1;
```

Don't forget to use the table alias in select, or you'll get the ambiguity error again. As far as the date, if I were writing this query I would just include the condition that the timesheet date is between your given date, and six days later [since between is inclusive, if you go seven days later you will get the next date as well]. Try this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, ts.date, ts.monday_am_task
FROM users u
JOIN timesheet_submission ts ON ts.user_id = u.user_id AND u.user_id = 1
WHERE ts.date BETWEEN '2015-04-06' AND DATE_ADD('2015-04-06', INTERVAL 6 DAY);
```

Here is more on [JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and on the [DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) function.

Comment: Wow, I was kind of out of my depth I guess, thanks so much! Would it be possible to use the "QUARTER" function also to find all of the above data but in Q1, Q2,... etc?

Comment: @tom I don't see why not. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067526/how-do-i-group-a-date-field-to-get-quarterly-results-in-mysql)